# IIS Url Rewriter to detect feed and redirect to Feedburner

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7.5

My site generates its rss feed in `http://mysite.com/sydnication/rss/articles` path. I want to redirect all users to feedburner when they access this url except for when feed burner's own user agent tries to access this url. This is the Url Rewrite rule that I thought should work, but it doesn't. Can some one take a look and tell me what's wrong?

```
<rule name="Feedburner redirection" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="/syndication/rss/articles" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://feeds.feedburner.com/articles" appendQueryString="false" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="FeedBurner" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove first forward slash (/) from match url, the input for match hasn't got slash at the beginning, and just in case I would add  `ignoreCase="true"`

```
<match url="syndication/rss/articles" ignoreCase="true" />
```